Trouble executing curl command in Python subprocess
I'm attempting to execute a curl command within a Python script using the subprocess module. However, I'm encountering issues with the execution and receiving inconsistent results. Here's the code snippet I'm using:
# Handler for the "/show_account_info" command
@bot.message_handler(commands=['show_account_info'])
def show_account_info(message):
    try:
        with open(f"{message.from_user.id}.txt", "r") as file:
            api_key = file.read().strip()
        
        curl_command = f"""
        curl -X 'GET' \\
          'https://api.website.com/v1/system/account' \\
          -H 'accept: application/json' \\
          "-H", f"X-API-Key: {api_key}"
        """
        print(f"Executing curl command: {curl_command}")  # Print the curl command being executed
        process = subprocess.Popen(curl_command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        output, error = process.communicate()

        print(output.decode('utf-8'))  # Print the JSON response

        if process.returncode != 0:
            print(f"Error executing curl command: {error.decode('utf-8')}")  # Print any error message from curl
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Error: API Key not set. Use 'Set API Key' to set your API Key.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")  # Print any other exception to the console

My terminal shows the command was received by the Telegram API, however, the curl isn't executed properly.
2024-04-22 22:41:43 - INFO - Received message from user user_id: Show Account Information
Other similar CURL commands, it works fine. But for this, it doesn't work and doesn't give me any error information. I can't figure out why it's not consistent. I've looked at the API key and made sure the curl command is written correctly, but I still have this issue.
For example, here's a working CURL command, that retrieves information for the task ID:
    curl_command = [
        "curl", "-X", "GET",
        f"https://api.website.com/v1/task?id={task_id}",
        "-H", "accept: application/json",
        "-H", f"X-API-Key: {api_key}"
    ]

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
What I tried:
I attempted to execute a curl command within my Python script using the subprocess.Popen function.
Expected outcome:
I expected the curl command to execute successfully and return the desired output from the API.
Actual result:
Curl command executed without any issues ran via terminal, and I received the expected output. However, other times the command failed, showing no error in the console. I'm unsure why this inconsistency is occurring and how to resolve it.

f"X-API-Key: {api_key}" You're already inside a triple-quoted f-string.   You don't need the extra "f" here.

Why do you try to create a shell=True version when you already have code (shown later in your question, in the curl_command = [ section) that works correctly with shell=False (which is better practice in the first place)?

(the shell=False version avoids security bugs if an attacker is able to inject a malicious API key that contains a shell injection, and would avoid room for similar bugs for any other parameterization you added in the future; it also prevents your code from being platform-specific, as which shell shell=True runs is OS-specific).

why not use requests or urllib.request instead of curl - it doesn't need  subprocess. There are even pages which can convert curl to requests - ie. Convert curl commands to code

you can use pages like httpbin.org to test your parameters - you can send requests or curl to httpbin.org/get or httpbin.org/post and it will send back your request and you can see if you send correctly formatted data.

@JohnGordon you should provide an answer or at least vote to close this as caused by a typo.
